# Gnuplot, take the average of each 2 rows

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot the *average of every two rows*. So **gnuplot** should take the first two rows, add them and then divide the result by two. Repeat the same thing on rows 3 and 4 etc..

So output of

```
10

20

30

40
```

would be a graph with points at

```
15

35
```

Any suggestions would be very welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
plot n=0, dataf using 0:(n==0 ? (a=$1, n=1, NaN) : (n=0, ($1+a)/2))
```

The flag variable "n" changes from 0 to 1 at each point, if it is zero, the present value is saved to "a" and NaN is returned, if it is one, the average of the present value and a is returned.

Check "help ternary operator".

A comma in a mathematical expression means "do this consecutively and only return the result of the last part", thats called "serial evaluation".

The first part in the plot (n=0) is not actually plotted. It just makes sure n is always initialized correctly for replotting, e.g. when you zoom in your plot.

Comment: I am very grateful for this answer. However, upon calling this, I am getting the following output :                                                         readLine() failed
Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process hasn't exited
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.exitValue(UNIXProcess.java:270)
 at jgp.GNUPlotRunner.run(JGPgnuplot.java:113)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745).

Here are the commands I used: n = 0,  plot [:8000.0] [:140.0] [:] '/home/john/muxplotsl/MUX01old' using 0:(n==0 ? (a=$1, n=1, NaN) : (n=0, ($1+a)/2))  with lines     title "Port 0 "

Comment: After medling around a bit, i found the cause to be the NaN statement. Is there any possible replacement?

Comment: Try using "1/0" instead of "NaN". But what strange gnuplot version are you using with all than java stuff? What is the third range specifier supposed to do? And plotting "with lines" can't work, because every other point is NaN, so no line will be drawn.